Blazor Net 8.0 Custom Authentication Not Working
I am trying to create my own Identity Model and Store using dapper.
But I am getting this error

Here is my sample code. Note I am using my custom MyIdentityUser and custom AddDapperStores.
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<MyIdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddDapperStores()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

I have tried this custom MyIdentityUser and AddDapperStores in Blazor NET 6.0; it works perfectly.

I finally found my problem..
In .NET 8 somehow the template includes a lot of extension and page for authentication. To solve it..I need to change all the codes under the folder Components/Account.
thanks all..

You can still add AspNetCore.Identity.DapperOrm version 6.0.0 which seems to resolve the problem.
